# Неккоректное сохранение Grid в изображение из-за DPI

Tags: c#, изображения, uwp, dpi

Добрый день. Сохраняю Grid в изображение с помощью RenderTargetBitmap. Вот кусок кода:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Grid);

var picker = new FileSavePicker();
picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPEG Image", new string[] { ".jpg" });
StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await
            BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
        byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                             BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                             (uint)Grid.Width, (uint)Grid.Height,
                             DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                             DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                             bytes);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

На устройстве с DPI = 96 сохраняет корректно, на устройстве со 120 - непонятная вещь, подобная как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574481/image-being-saved-from-canvas-is-not-rendered-properly . Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Странно, [вот тут](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-render-to-bitmap-dd4f549f/sourcecode?fileId=86717&pathId=2647585) практически такой же код. Вы точно уверены, что у вас не бежит на устройстве старый код?

Comment: @VladD да, я прямо запускаю на второй машине в режиме дебага прогу, может из-за того что лежит внутри Грида Canvas? Для которого Background устанавливается с помощью brush, который получается из softwareBitmap с DPI 96?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим образом:
Заменил это:

```
encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                         BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                         (uint)Grid.Width, (uint)Grid.Height,
                         DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                         DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                         bytes);
```

На это:

```
encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                     BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                    (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                    (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                    DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                    DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi, bytes);
```

Comment: Гениально! PixelWidth ведь может не совпадать с Width!